# C# with CMake - Add service reference (wsdl file)

Tags: c#, cmake, wsdl

I'm in the process of converting a c# project to be generated with cmake (version 3.8). In the solution generated with visual studio, a wsdl file is added as service reference with these settings:

[image]

How can I add the wsdl file to my cmake generated project?

I found nothing about cmake and wsdl files so I would be thankful for even some pointer in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a wsdl file as service reference in visual studio generates .cs file(s). Those can be added as usual with cmake.

To create the files in cmake, call the corresponding tools (wsdl.exe[1]).

I will expand this answer when I manage to complete the process in CMake.

[1] Probably. I managed to create a cs file that is quite close to the file I was expecting but not yet identical.